# Change the Drupal theme according to the day time

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, themes, drupal-modules

I want to write a drupal module which will toggle between 2 themes according to the time of the server.

Please say, which hook should I implement.

Should I use

```
function hook_init(){
    global $custom_theme;
    $custom_theme = (<condition> ? 'theme1' : 'theme2');
}
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work in your module.  I have tested it in one of my own and it works fine.